# Format String by replacing special chars

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to format following string into array

I have a string with 3 values inside (but could be more). issue is that i have many special char inside my string ex:

```
 MyString = "'O''Neil, Bill','Dave, John','NYC'"
```

**Result should be**: as you can see i want to split my string into 3 values on **comma** while removing **single quotes**. Furture more, I want to keep **comma** in their names & 2 single quotes together should be replaced into 1 single quote

```
MyArray(0) = O'Neil, Bill
MyArray(1) = Dave, John
MyArray(2) = NYC
```

**What I tried so far**:

```
Dim MyArray() As String = MyString .Replace("'","").Split(",")
```

Issue is that ONeil should have 1 single quote ex: `O'Neil`:

```
MyArray(0) = ONeil
MyArray(1) = Bill
MyArray(2) = Dave
MyArray(3) = John
MyArray(4) = NYC
```

Comment: You could replace the double quotes with a temp character and change it back later (`.Replace("''","TEMPITEM")`. However this would still cause issues if there was an empty item in the comma array: `'Bill','Dave, John','NYC', '', 'VDWWD'`. Better try to make sure the source string is cleaned up.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like these values were prepped for use in an SQL statement, and if that's true it's using entirely the wrong approach. In fact, it's actively dangerous. Instead, you need to look into parameterized queries. That said, you can split on the `','` string, remove the leading `'` from the first item and trailing `'` from the last item, and then replace any paired `''` with a single `'`.

Comment: How about splitting on the string `"','"` (that is single-quote, comma, single quote)? Then you can replace 2 single quotes with a single single quote. This assumes, that a name can't look like `"'John '','' Doe'"`.

Comment: See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/d4qs8Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a real CSV-Parser like the out-of-the-box available [`TextFieldParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=net-7.0), you can achieve the desired result with pure string methods:

The key is to split on `','` and to replace two `''` with one `'`:

```
Dim MyString = "'O''Neil, Bill','Dave, John','NYC'"
Dim columnSeparator As String() = {"','"}
Dim MyArray() As String = (From token In MyString.Split(columnSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None)
                           Select token.Trim("'"c).Replace("''", "'")).ToArray()
```

Comment: What if there is an empty item? `"'O''Neil, Bill','Dave, John', '', 'NYC'"`

Comment: @VDWWD: If the csv is not properly formatted you should fix that first, if possible. Or use an available csv parser like i've said in the answer. I've assumed that the format is always same. This is a simple approach that doesn't cover edge cases, it's more like a workaround.